# How to AutoComplete an Address and get Lat/Long of that address in #flutter?

Tags: autocomplete, flutter

[image: Auto Complete Address]

How to AutoComplete an Address and get Lat/Long of that address in #flutter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple google maps address search with autocomplete in flutter and get latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870508/how-to-create-a-simple-google-maps-address-search-with-autocomplete-in-flutter-a)

Comment: I created a simple utility class for the problem - https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing you can do directly with flutter. You need to call an API for that service. In a recent project I used [HERE Autocomplete](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/quick-start.html) and [HERE Geocoder](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/quick-start.html) for such a service, which worked quite well.

In Flutter you just need to work with the responses of those APIs. In my case the [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) was the perfect solution (there is even an example in the docs which is a good starting point).

Comment: I tried it out, the company is crap. It says I've exceeded the # of projects I'm allowed and I didn't even create 1 project.

Comment: Is there any free service to use map address to lat-long, lat-long to address and place autocomplete provider? Kindly suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Checkout my custom utility class for places auto complete https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148

Answer (score 3):

You have to [make HTTP Networking Requests in Flutter](https://flutter.io/networking/) to the [Place Autocomplete service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) that is part of the [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service).

Comment: Is there any free service to use map address to lat-long, lat-long to address and place autocomplete provider? Kindly suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Implemented the above for easy use - https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148