# How to create a simple google maps address search with autocomplete in flutter and get latitude and longitude?

Tags: search, flutter, autocomplete, maps, google-places-autocomplete

I'm new at Flutter and I'm trying to build a simple google maps app. I've already implemented google maps to the app and it is running perfect.

But now I want to add google maps autocomplete and I can't find a simple tutorial or example that is focused on it.

I have a TextField and I want to show places and addresses below it according to what the user types.

After showing the results, I need to get its latitude and longitude to mark on the map. The code below represents my BottomSheet, that contains my TexField and need to implement some list below it after some written text.

```java
void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),
                      child: TextField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Para onde vamos?",
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 15.0),
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            onPressed: searchAndNavigate,
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                          )
                        ),
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            searchAddr = val;
                          }
                        );
                      },
                      onSubmitted: (term) {
                        searchAndNavigate();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

[image: Current screen]

Comment: I have created a simple implantation for the above https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [flutter_google_places](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_google_places) plugin which shows the places in the autocomplete list as you type it and also returns lat and long of the place/address selected.

===== Working code =======

1. Add `flutter_google_places` plugin and import it in your dart file.
2. Add [geo_coder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder) plugin and import it in same dart file. (Required to access geocoding services)
3. Generate google api key for your project.

main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const kGoogleApiKey = "Api_key";

GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: demo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  demoState createState() => new demoState();
}

class demoState extends State<demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // show input autocomplete with selected mode
            // then get the Prediction selected
            Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
            displayPrediction(p);
          },
          child: Text('Find address'),

        )
      )
    );
  }

  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

When you tap on Find Address button, it opens new screen with built-in search app bar in which you can type address / place you are looking for which shows corresponding results in autocomplete list and prints `lat` and `long` of the place you selected.

[image]

```
lat: 52.3679843
lng: 4.9035614
```

Comment: Hi, @DK15. Thank you. Do you know any tutorial showing how to implement that? I'm a beginner yet.

Comment: I updated my answer with working code sample. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi, DK15! Thank you. The code is working with my API Key. I would like to put the results returned from PlacesAutocomplete to a custom listview. So I would like to store it on a List variable and print it. Is that possible to do? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can make use of `placeId` to get id of the location you selected and its corresponding `address` to store in custom listview and can access it using the variable you declare for listview.

Comment: Also, if your original question has been answered, you can accept my answer and upvote it so it would be helpful for others to know as well :-)

Comment: Sure! Thank you again!

Comment: You did all the work for us. Thanks it works perfectly.

Comment: @DK15 can you please show the import statement because I import `flutter_google_places` as `import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';` and I got the error for `GoogleMapsPlaces` as undefined class.

Comment: @DK15 you should add a token id to your show() call and use the same token in your place details request. otherwise, you'll be charged on each request separately.

Comment: @sainu `import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';` ended up working

Comment: how to implement without open another screen?

Comment: @BloodLoss mode: Mode.overlay

Comment: import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';

Comment: I want to be able to use gps as the current location how can I do that in the same view?

Comment: The `Api_key` is google cloud platform `Places API` key. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key

Comment: What is `Prediction`? Please provide your imports with your example