# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PlaceDetails')

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-places-api

Help me with this error:
[image]

I am trying to get place value/name from `displayPrediction()` and show it in my textformfield
Here is the call from TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'From'),
  onTap: () async {
   Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show( context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
   displayPrediction(p);
  },
)
```

[image]
I want to save the place back to textformfield.

My `displayPrediction()`:

```
Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
      print(address);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the return type of getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId), can you post code for this method ??

Comment: I followed from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55877236/11545939 I am first time ever working on API.

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout your google places import dependency. It should be as follow

```
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
```

Also, checkout you have initialised the _places as

```
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY");
```

Comment: `import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';

const kGoogleApiKey = "MY_API_KEY";

GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);`

Comment: I think you should remove this imports "import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';" "import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';"

Comment: Then check out that GoogleMapsPlaces is you are using from the correct package. like if you are using multiple dependencies it might possible that all different dependencies might have a class with same name like GoogleMapsPlaces.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with p.description. I faced the same issue.
Use it like this :

```
List address = [];
  address.add(p.description);

  print(address);
```