# How can I pick the value from places from PlacesAutocomplete and store it in TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-places-api, google-places

I want to get places with PlacesAutocomplete and store it in my TextFormField.
I am calling `displayPrediction()` from `TextFormFeild()`

```
TextFormField(
                    decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'From'),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show( 
                        context: context,
                        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                        mode: Mode.overlay,
                        //language: "en",
                        //components: [Component (Component.country, "en")],
                        );
                      displayPrediction(p);
                    },
                  ),
```

Here is the `displayPrediction()` :

```
Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
      print(address);
    }
  }
```

The variables kGoogleApiKey and _places

```
const kGoogleApiKey = "My_API_Key";

GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
```

**I want to get the place after tapping on my TextFormField and display the same place in that same TextFormField**
[image]

And I am getting this error after selecting a place- [_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PlaceDetails')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59475091/11545939)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is demo

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(      controller: _controller ,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'From'),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show( 
                        context: context,
                        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                        mode: Mode.overlay,
                        //language: "en",
                        //components: [Component (Component.country, "en")],
                        );
                      displayPrediction(p);
                    },
                  ),
```

it look like you are using geocoder library

```
Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);
      setState(() {
         _controller.text = address.first.featureName;
      });

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
      print(address);
    }
  }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you it works fine for 'From', but it displays the same place on 'To' and if I select 'To' TextFormFeild to change the place it is showing an error: _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PlaceDetails')

Comment: use different `final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();` for 'TO' field

Comment: I have created different displayPrediction and _controller, but even after that 'TO' is showing the error

Comment: It is type casting issue , recheck your variable datatype

Comment: await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

Comment: The error occurs in between `_places**.**getDetailsByPlaceId...`

Comment: what is type of _places??

Comment: GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

Comment: which library are you using this `flutter_google_places 0.2.3` or `flutter_google_places_autocomplete 0.1.3` ??

Comment: check the return type of this method `_places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);`

Comment: I don't know but it is showing the error, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475091/typeerror-type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-placedetails

Comment: let me know when u find solution:)