# Google search autocomplete using search box

Tags: flutter, maps

How to add Google Maps Autocomplete search box in flutter?

I want to add an autocomplete search box in google maps using dart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a simple google maps address search with autocomplete in flutter and get latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870508/how-to-create-a-simple-google-maps-address-search-with-autocomplete-in-flutter-a)

Answer (score 0):

add dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
  flutter_google_places:
```

after that, you can use this method

```
Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
    // show input autocomplete with selected mode
    // then get the Prediction selected
    Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
      context: context,
      apiKey: 'your_api_key',
//      onError: onError,
      mode: Mode.overlay,
      language: "en",
      components: [Component(Component.country, "in")],
    );

  }
```