# I want to search for address from google maps API and fill it automatically in Text Form Field

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I'm looking to use a TextFormField for typing and auto completing address and get data based on the address such as Street, City and State and in the future use Google Maps to locate the address. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a simple google maps address search with autocomplete in flutter and get latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870508/how-to-create-a-simple-google-maps-address-search-with-autocomplete-in-flutter-a)

Comment: I suppose the question is similar but it seems outdated so I have tried it and the answers there don't seem to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate more what did not work by following the suggestion duplicate question?

Comment: It looks like the answer to the linked question is still using Geocoding which was unnecessary since the flutter library being used in the answer already had a places webservice client library dependency.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.